# MATLAB multidimensional matrix to NumPy matrix conversion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab, matrix

I want to write this MATLAB matrix in python : `U = [Q S P;S H G;P G E];`

where P,Q, S ,H,G, E has a dimension of 103 by 103.

This is what is wrote in Python but it's the  wrong syntax, `U = np.array([[Q ,S, P ],[S, H, G], [P, G, E]])` and  gives me wrong dimension

The correct output dimension  is 309 by 309

Comment: Please provide a [mre], emphasis on *minimal*, including an explicit example and expected result. I guess [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) could help.

Comment: My guess is the `numpy` `U` is (3,3,103,103), a 4d array.  My MATLAB is bit rusty (and I can't run Octave on this computer at the moment) but apparently that syntax concatenates the `Q S P` matrices into one, and then does another layer of concatenating for the rows.  That can be done with a set of `hstack` and `vstack`, or with `np.block` as a short hand.  You should be able to figure out what that `np.array` is doing by looking at simpler examples, like `np.array([Q,S])` or even `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`.

Answer (score 2):

[`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) is closest to what MATLAB does as noted by @MichaelSzczesny in a comment.

```
import numpy as np

rows = 103
cols = 103

Q = np.ones((rows,cols)) * 1
S = np.ones((rows,cols)) * 2
P = np.ones((rows,cols)) * 3
H = np.ones((rows,cols)) * 4
G = np.ones((rows,cols)) * 5
E = np.ones((rows,cols)) * 6

U = np.block([
    [Q, S, P], 
    [S, H, G],
    [P, G, E]
    ])

print('U has dimensions', U.shape)
# U has dimensions (309, 309)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do multiple concatenations of the arrays with [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Example:

```
import numpy as np

rows = 103
cols = 103

Q = np.array([[0]*cols]*rows)
S = np.array([[1]*cols]*rows)
P = np.array([[2]*cols]*rows)
H = np.array([[3]*cols]*rows)
G = np.array([[4]*cols]*rows)
E = np.array([[5]*cols]*rows)

U = np.concatenate((np.concatenate((Q,S,P)),np.concatenate((S,H,G)),np.concatenate((P,G,E))), 1)

print("Output dimensions: ", len(U[0]), " by ", len(U))
```

Comment: try using `np.zeros((rows,cols),int)+3`